# Does $\mathrm{Homeo}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ admit a deformation-retract to $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am wondering whether there exists a deformation-retract from the self-homeomorphism group $G = \mathrm{Homeo}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, to $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$. Here we give $G$ the compact-open topology (for example).

Would anyone have any suggestions or hints on how to approach this question?